# Selenium Grid and protecting it's end point with AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We are running selenium grid from helm chart [v0.20.1] in AWS EKS. As part of our organisation's guidelines we are forced to apply WAF rules to the selenium grid's end point with the query parameter as described below. However after applying the rule and adding the necessary param and key except the Graph QL end point rest are not working .  Could you please provide any insight on this. Can this be achieved

https://selenium.dev.aws.fiction.com/ui?waf_bypass=key  --> UI failed to load as it is blocking the internal calls
https://selenium.dev.aws.fiction.com?waf_bypass=key --> Test run fails
https://selenium.dev.aws.fiction.com/graphql?waf_bypass=key --> this works as this is a simple call to that end point .

Thank you in advance!